# Sharepoint REST API empty value on expanded lookup columns causes error

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list with lookup columns.  When I get an item from the list and expand the lookup columns, I get an error if any of the lookup column values are empty.

For example if I have a list with the look up column: **files**, and I want to get the column: **preview_link**, I have a URL as follows:

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List Title')/Items('39')$select=*,files/Title,files/preview_link&$expand=files
```

That works fine, except if one of the items in files has an empty value for **preview_link**.  In that case I get an error:

> Cannot get value for projected field files_x005f_preview_link.

Is there any way around this short of having to put some dummy value for look up items that don't have a value for preview_link?  Is this what Microsoft expects developers to do?  Maybe I'm missing something simple, though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this still an open issue in SP API: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4478.

But there is an workaround, using **RenderListDataAsStream**. This way the call is going to return all the data, including the lookup values.

Javascript example (Thanks to Gautam Sheth [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/249255/85386)):

*Field1 and Field2 are single line of text column and Field3 is a person/group column*

**Call** :

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
        "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('LISTNAME')/RenderListDataAsStream",
    type: "POST",   
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data.Row)
    },
    error:function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
})
```

**Response** :

```
[object Object]
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Field1: "",
         Field2: "",
         Field3: [
            0: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: { },
               email: "example@example.org",
               id: "1",
               title: "EXAMPLE"
            },
            1: { },
            2: { },
            length: 3
         ]},
      length: 1
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still a thing in SP2019. But there is an other workaround: define a calculated column in the lookup list and expand that column in your query. Use ISBLANK function to ensure that it always has a value.