# Look Up value through REST without select or expand

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

Can we get the lookup value from SharePoint list through REST without using the query operators `(select/expand)` ?

Comment: Well you can use CAML query instead of the select/expand option, I can't see why you would want to do it though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RenderListDataAsStream` endpoint to fetch lookup values without using select or expand. This works for User fields as well as Managed metadata columns as well.

Try with the below sample code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
        "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/RenderListDataAsStream",
    type: "POST",   
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success:function(data){
        // iterate over data.Row
        console.log(data.Row);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Reference - [Working with list items by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But it is giving error while using with 'GET' method . I need get values.

Comment: It is a POST method, can you check with the snippet i posted here ? It is not a GET request

Comment: Yeah. It works . Thanks for your response. If possible please suggest best reference for "RenderListDataAsStream" explaining where to use and how can we use that. In official document it directly used without explanation.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help. You can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer ! It will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. Thanks. Additionally, you can refer [this](https://www.mavention.nl/blogs-cat/getting-term-label-values-with-the-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-endpoint/) and [this](https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-fetch-lookup-single-managed-metadata-field-values/) link which are blogs.

Comment: @GautamSheth, `RenderListDataAsStream` method handles the list threshold error? I am trying to get the items from list more than 5K. Even after I apply filter query is giving `exception: -2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException`. Will this method solve this issue?